# Line still appearing but not existing in metadata of shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, display, erase

For a project, I had to merge the cells of a grid to upscale it.

It was possible to merge all that I wanted but there is kind of a display problem. There is a line which appears visually but that does not exist in the metadata or anywhere (see below, as you can see there are 2 undesired lines, the first on the column of the selected cell and the other one more on the right)

[image]

What is weird is that when I select the cell, it is selected as one cell as if this line doesn't exist. Same in the metadata, there is no information about this line.

It is not a problem for my analysis as this line doesn't really exist but I would like to display it properly so would you have any suggestion on how to erase this line (even manually)?

Comment: Looks like they are multipart features. In the processing toolbox run the `Vector Geometry > Multipart to singleparts` tool and see if they change into multiple features.

Comment: Thx for the tip @TeddyTedTed. Unfortunately, the line is still there

Comment: Right, that's expected, but can you now select just one half of that feature?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I can select just one part. I am not sure to understand what it means though: why now it is divided in two but on the first shp it is just one entity?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments the features which have the line through them are multipart features. These are single features with multiple geometries.

If the different parts of the multipart features are touching perfectly then using the `Vectory geometry > Fix geometries` *should* merge them together into a singlepart feature.

If that doesn't work then go to `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer` and buffer it by 0, see if that works.

Comment: Wow, that is really interesting: now that I used the `Fix geometry`, I obtain the same shp than before: I still have the line but when I select the cell, it is just one and unique cell

Comment: Hmm, try buffering instead (see edit)

Comment: Thx again. It doesn't work though... So I tried by hand to merge two cells on the shp obtain from `Multipart to singleparts` and when I do it, the cells are merged but the line is still there !!! I really think that it is impossible to take off